# Difference between treemap and concurrentskiplistmap? Possibility to use NavigableMap with a map structure for duplicate keys?

Tags: java, dictionary

I'm a beginner in Java. I have a method as below:

```
 public void time_filter(Long t1, Long t2){
    NavigableMap<Long, Operations_enter> time_map = new TreeMap<Long, Operations_enter>();
    for(int i=0; i< tm.size();i++){
        Operations_enter op = new Operations_enter();
        op.cpuid_enter = cpu.get(i);
        op.func_enter = stt.get(i);
        op.time_enter = tm.get(i);
        op.src_enter = tok.get(i);

        time_map.put(op.time_enter, op);

    }


    for(Map.Entry<Long, Operations_enter> entry: time_map.subMap(t1, true, t2, true).entrySet()){
        Integer time_func = entry.getValue().func_enter;
        System.out.println(" Filtered function numbers corresponding to given time range is" + time_func);

        }
```

So like seen above, I implement a `NavigableMap` with `TreeMap` and Im able to filter for a given range using the `subMap` method in NavigableMap. But I have a problem now, the `time_enter` contains some duplicate keys, so when I use `TreeMap`, the values get overwritten by the latest added duplicate value. I understand that it is how `TreeMap` works. I tried using `ConcurrentSkipListMap` too, but the result was the same.

What is the actual difference between `ConcurrentSkipListMap` and `TreeMap`?? And is there a possibility to implement `NavigableMap` with either `TreeMap` or `ConcurrentSkipListMap` and at the same time have the duplicate values included in the `NavigableMap`?

**EDIT**  The code looks like this now:

```
  NavigableMap<Long, Operations_enter> time_map = new TreeMap<Long, Operations_enter>(new Comparator<Long>() {
        public int compare(Long o1, Long o2) {
            return o1.equals(o2) ? 1 : o1.compareTo(o2);
        }
    });
    for(int i=0; i< tm.size();i++){
        Operations_enter op = new Operations_enter();
        op.cpuid_enter = cpu.get(i);
        op.func_enter = stt.get(i);
        op.time_enter = tm.get(i);
        op.src_enter = tok.get(i);

        time_map.put(op.time_enter, op);

    }

    for(Map.Entry<Long, Operations_enter> entry: time_map.subMap(t1, true, t2, true).entrySet()){

       Integer time_func = entry.getValue().func_enter;
        System.out.println(" Filtered function numbers corresponding to given time range is" + time_func);
     }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ConcurrentSkipListMap is a NavigableMap implementation designed to be safely used from multiple threads concurrently.  This is its main difference from TreeMap. Since your `time_map` is a local variable it can be accessed only from current thread and you dont need ConcurrentSkipListMap.

If you need a TreeMap that allows duplicate keys, you can try to make a custom Comparator that never returns 0:

```
TreeMap<Integer, Object> m = new TreeMap<>(new Comparator<Integer>() {
    public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
        return o1.equals(o2) ? 1 : o1.compareTo(o2);
    }
});
m.put(0, 0);
m.put(1, 1);
m.put(1, 1);
m.put(1, 1);
m.put(2, 2);
m.put(3, 3);
m.put(4, 4);
System.out.println(m.subMap(0, false, 3, true));
```

output

```
{1=1, 1=1, 2=2, 3=3}
```

note that it breaks Map contract which may cause unexpected behavior eg m.containsKey(1) returns false instead you need to use m.subMap(0, false, 2, false) != null

Comment: If you need a TreeMap that allows duplicate keys, try to make a custom Comparator that never returns 0

Comment: Can you give me an example on how to do that? Or send me a link which might help me perhaps?

Comment: I need a small help. I did like you suggested and now I get the duplicate values too. But the value corresponding to the t1 in the submap is not displayed. Can you look at the code and tell me where I am going wrong? I have edited the code in my post.

Answer (score 7):

The `ConcurrentSkipListMap` and `TreeMap` classes are both `NavigableMap` implementations. Implementing that interface means they keep their keys in sorted order. This they have in common. In other ways, they are quite different.

> Possibility to use NavigableMap with a map structure for duplicate keys?

No, neither `TreeMap` nor `ConcurrentSkipListMap` can handle duplicate keys. When doing a [`put`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#put(K,V)), an existing key has its previous value replaced by the arriving value.

> Difference between treemap and concurrentskiplistmap?

3 differences: Nulls, Performance, and Concurrency.

## Nulls

- A `TreeMap` **allows null values**, while keys must be non-null.
- A `ConcurrentSkipListMap` **forbids nulls** in either keys or values.

## Performance

A `ConcurrentSkipListMap` uses [skip list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list) technology. This class may show very fast search performance while still allowing fast insertions.

A skip list is scalable, maintaining performance with large numbers of entries, even while insertions are being made.

## Concurrency

As others noted, a `ConcurrentSkipListMap` is made to be [concurrent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_(computer_science)) and [thread-safe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety). A `TreeMap` is not.

## Conclusion

- If you have a large number of entries, use `ConcurrentSkipListMap` rather than `TreeMap`.
- If you are accessing your `NavigableMap` across threads, use `ConcurrentSkipListMap`, never `TreeMap`.
- For smaller numbers of entries accessed within a single thread, use `TreeMap`.

---

Here is a table summarizing the various `Map` implementations. Click/Tap to zoom.

[image: A table describing aspects of the various Map implementations in Java 11.]

Comment: A small correction: A TreeMap does allow null keys. It's the map's default comparator that doesn't allow null keys but you can provide one that supports them. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48687927/897024

Answer (score 0):

Maps allow only one value for a given key. What you need is a Multimap. The JDK itself contains no implementation of a Multimap ("because they aren't used all that commonly" according to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html).

There are implementations of Multimap in some libraries like Google Guava or Apache Commons Collections.

Have a look at Guava's TreeMultimap at http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/TreeMultimap.html

Comment: Yes I know about MultiMaps, can MultiMaps be used with `NavigableMap`?

Comment: A MultiMap is no Map and therefore can't be a NavigableMap. What you may use is the method *getKeys* that returns a NavigableSet which is quite similar to a NavigableMap and provides *descendingSet* and *descendingIterator*.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the functionality of 
    Multimap<K,V> 
using as target container
    Map<K, List<V>>